# Month Offset in BO 4.0 (IDT)

Tags: sql-server, business-objects

I want to make a month offset in reference to the current date (I am using BusinessObjects 4.0 Information Design Tool).
So for example, there is a column with the value 201505 (meaning May 2015), the new column should have the value '2' (assuming the current month is 201503 - March 2015).
Another example if the first column has the value '201410', the new column should have the corresponding value '-7'.

I tried to implement the 'month offset' column by analyzing the 'Current Month Num - 12' column, which is defined as follows:

```
cast(
convert(
    char(6), 
    dateadd(m, -12,
                left(cast(( Zeitdimension.Year_Month_NUM ) as char(6)), 4) 
                + '-' 
                + right(cast(( Zeitdimension.Year_Month_NUM ) as char(6)), 2)
                + '-01')
    , 112
) 
as int
)
```

(Zeitdimension.Year_Month_NUM has the values such as 201402, 201901...)

However I do not understand the convert and dateadd functions, nor I was able to find anything about them on the internet.

The idea I have is to adapt the definition of 'Current Month Num - 12' column by taking the values in the first column (values as 201401, 201502) and subtracting those values from the current date (values such as 201501, 201403...).

Can anybody help me with the following:

1. explain the convert, dateadd functions as well as the expression above
2. help me define the 'month offset' column

Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functions `convert` and `dateadd` are SQL Server functions, not BusinessObject functions. You can more information on them in the [Books Online](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174318(v=sql.110).aspx) documentation in the section *Transact-SQL Reference* > *Built-in Functions*.

Regarding the existing expression: the innermost breaks up the existing column value and converts it into a date, e.g. `201412` to `2014-12-01`.

```
left(cast(( Zeitdimension.Year_Month_NUM ) as char(6)), 4) 
+ '-' 
+ right(cast(( Zeitdimension.Year_Month_NUM ) as char(6)), 2)
+ '-01')
```

The `dateadd` function then substracts 12 months.
`convert` changes the date into a character string (format `YYYYMMDD`) and drops the last 2 digits, thus resulting in `201312`.

Lastly, `cast`changes the datatype from a character string into an integer.

You can't start doing calculations with the resulting values (e.g. subtract `201401` from `201501`) as this will not take into account that you're dealing with years and months). The latter example will return `100` instead of `12`.

Instead, to calculate the offset in number of months compared to the current date, try the following expression:

```
datediff(mm
        ,dateadd(d, datepart(d, getdate()) * -1, getdate())
        ,left(cast(( Zeitdimension.Year_Month_NUM ) as char(6)), 4) 
        + '-' 
        + right(cast(( Zeitdimension.Year_Month_NUM ) as char(6)), 2)
        + '-01')
```

This will take the current date, subtract the current number of days (so you always end up at the first date of the month) and then uses `datediff` to calculate the difference in number of months.

The available datetime functions has improved significantly in the latest SQL Server versions, removing the need to perform such convoluted conversions. Again, have a look at Books Online to see what is available in the version of SQL Server you're using.

Comment: thx for the comment.
The solution in tried is not working properly. For example when I have 201601 in the fist column, when I calculate 'Month Current Offest Num' I get the value '98'...
Can you suggest the solution for my question?

Comment: It seems ok. However, there is 1 month difference. For example in reference to the '201502' value, the result of the expression is '0', and not '-1' as I expected (again in reference to the current month year 201503). How can I adapt that?

Comment: I don't have a sql server environment at hand to test it out. Given the Books Online link and the info provided, with a little effort, you should be able to figure it out.

Comment: think I figured it out -> by changing 'dateadd(d, datepart(d, getdate()) * -1, getdate())' to 'dateadd(d, datepart(d, getdate()) * -1 +1, getdate())', I get the expected result. Many thanks for your help! :)